# c# Compare datetime with 2 other dates

Tags: c#, datetime

Im trying to compare a specific date `periodDate` which is stored in a xml file with one `stopDate` and `startDate`.

So if `periodDate` is between `startDate` and `StopDate` insert data:

```
if ((DateTime.Compare(periodTime, startDatePer1) == 1) 
   && (periodTime.CompareTo(stopDatePer1) == 1)) 
{
   // ... insert some data to databse                 
}
else if ((DateTime.Compare(periodTime, startDatePer2) == 1)
        && (periodTime.CompareTo(stopDatePer2) == 1))
{
   // ..... insert data 
}
```

My problem is that im stuck on the first `if` even if the `periodDate` is NOT between `startDate` and `stopDate`.

Comment: What's wrong with `if(periodDate >= startDate && periodDate <= endDate)`?

Comment: Why are you stuck, didn't get you on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is both `DateTime.Compare(periodTime, startDatePer1) == 1` and `periodTime.CompareTo(stopDatePer1) == 1` translate to `>`.

Change the second to -1 and it should work. But you don't need to use `Compare` or `CompareTo`, just use `<` and `>`

Answer (score 4):

Why not:

```
if(periodDate > startDate && periodDate < stopDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (periodTime >= startDatePer1 && periodTime <= startDatePer2)
{
  // Then insert data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most readable form is:

```
if (startDate < periodTime && periodTime < stopDate) {
}
```

As this more clearly shows period time lying **between** startDate and stopDate ie startDate < periodTime < stopDate

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) library includes the class **TimeRange** with support of various time period relations:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void TimeRangeSample()
{
  // --- time range 1 ---
  TimeRange timeRange1 = new TimeRange(
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 14, 0, 0 ),
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 18, 0, 0 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1: " + timeRange1 );
  // > TimeRange1: 22.02.2011 14:00:00 - 18:00:00 | 04:00:00

  // --- time range 2 ---
  TimeRange timeRange2 = new TimeRange(
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 15, 0, 0 ),
    new TimeSpan( 2, 0, 0 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange2: " + timeRange2 );
  // > TimeRange2: 22.02.2011 15:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 02:00:00

  // --- time range 3 ---
  TimeRange timeRange3 = new TimeRange(
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 16, 0, 0 ),
    new DateTime( 2011, 2, 22, 21, 0, 0 ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange3: " + timeRange3 );
  // > TimeRange3: 22.02.2011 16:00:00 - 21:00:00 | 05:00:00

  // --- relation ---
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetRelation( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): Enclosing
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange3 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetRelation( timeRange3 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetRelation( TimeRange3 ): EndInside
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange3.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange3.GetRelation( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange3.GetRelation( TimeRange2 ): StartInside

  // --- intersection ---
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetIntersection( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ):
  //             22.02.2011 15:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 02:00:00
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange3 ): " +
                     timeRange1.GetIntersection( timeRange3 ) );
  // > TimeRange1.GetIntersection( TimeRange3 ):
  //             22.02.2011 16:00:00 - 18:00:00 | 02:00:00
  Console.WriteLine( "TimeRange3.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ): " +
                     timeRange3.GetIntersection( timeRange2 ) );
  // > TimeRange3.GetIntersection( TimeRange2 ):
  //             22.02.2011 16:00:00 - 17:00:00 | 01:00:00
} // TimeRangeSample
```